# How to set an empty collection in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jboss, jpql

The problem is a bit awkward. I have a Subject (some talks on a forum) with Comments, and each Comment can have multiple moderation Flags.

Using JBoss, I make a RESTful Webservice Request with RestEasy. The Jackson technology transform my Subject into JSON.

My request to find the Subject is :

```
Select s from Subject s JOIN FETCH s.comments WHERE s.id = :id
```

The problem is that each Comment has now a `PersistentBag` instead of a List, and JBoss throws :

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: io.robusta.fora.domain.Comment.flags, no session or session was closed (through reference chain: 

java.util.ArrayList[0]
->io.robusta.fora.domain.Subject["comments"]
->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]
->io.robusta.fora.domain.Comment["flags"])
```

In fact I just want to ignore these flags in **this particular request**. So what I do is awful but works :

```
for (Comment c : comments ){c.setFlags(new ArrayList<Flag>());}
```

But to avoid this awful loop, is there a way to force this empty value in the JPQL query ?

Comment: Another way is to limit the depth of Json serialization but because the Json is a bit more complicated, I may need to go deeper in another branch

Comment: Use Jackson views or mixins, or even transform your subjects into DTOs containing the data you want to serialize, and not more.

Comment: I don't want a technology answer, because I could also use the mustache template engine. And I don't want to create 3-4 DTOs around each domain object because one day I will not need flags, then not accounts, etc.

Comment: Try initialising flags to ArrayList in Comment entity? private List<Flag> flags = new ArrayList<Flag>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell Hibernate to simply ignore the existence of a collection: it will be proxied using its own implementation of collections (PersistentBag or PersistentList) and filled with data or not.
I think it's a up to your Serializer to take it in account.

You could write a custom serializer in Jackson assigned to `flags` collection that would use method `Hibernate.isInitialized()` to check if the collection has been initialized to decide wether to serialize it or not. (but this is a technology answer...)